# Ensure tasks are completing in order

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

We are using mailgun and some of our users are placed on the suppression list. It can be tedious to remove multiple users at once so I want to do the same through the API. I also want to save some information regarding why the users email was bounced so I can relay it back to them. I'm doing this like so:

```
fs.readFile('emails.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) { 
  if (err) throw err;
  var emails = data.split(',');
  async.eachSeries(emails, function(email, cb){
    options.url = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/XXXXX.com/bounces/'+email

    request.get(options, function(err, res, body){
      body = JSON.parse(body);
      error_code = body.error;
      bounced_at = body.created_at;

      var str = "\n Error code: "+body.error+" for email: "+email+" was bounced at: "+body.created_at
      fs.appendFile("output.txt", str, function(err){
        if(err) console.log(err)
        console.log("Details were saved to output.txt")
      })
    });
    request.del(options, function(err, res, body){
      if(err){
        cb(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Email: '+email+' has been unsuppressed');
      }
    })
    cb(null);
  }, function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('All bounced emails removed')
    }
  });
});
```

Below is a test with 5 users.

Input:

`test1@ah.com,test2@ah.com,test3@ah.com,test4@ah.com,test5@ah.com`

Output:

`Error code: 4.4.4 for email: test4@ah.com was bounced at: Tue, 30 May 2017 11:40:17 UTC
Error code: 3.3.3 for email: test3@ah.com was bounced at: Tue, 30 May 2017 11:40:05 UTC
Error code: 2.2.2 for email: test2@ah.com was bounced at: Tue, 30 May 2017 11:39:57 UTC
Error code: 1.1.1 for email: test1@ah.com was bounced at: Tue, 30 May 2017 11:39:45 UTC
Error code: 5.5.5 for email: test5@ah.com was bounced at: Tue, 30 May 2017 11:40:27 UTC`

We can see that these don't complete in order, which is fine. Sure this is enough in the async docs [here](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each).

> Note, that since this function applies iteratee to each item in parallel, there is no guarantee that the iteratee functions will complete in order.

However, when I test with ten emails:

`test1@ah.com,test2@ah.com,test3@ah.com,test4@ah.com,test5@ah.com,test6@ah.com,test7@ah.com,test7@ah.com,test8@ah.com,test9@ah.com,test10@ah.com`

This is the output:

`Error code: 2.2.2 for email: test2@ah.com was bounced at: Tue, 30 May 2017 11:43:57 UTC
Error code: undefined for email: test10@ah.com was bounced at: undefined
Error code: 1.1.1 for email: test1@ah.com was bounced at: Tue, 30 May 2017 11:43:50 UTC
Error code: 8.8.8 for email: test8@ah.com was bounced at: Tue, 30 May 2017 11:44:43 UTC
Error code: 3.3.3 for email: test3@ah.com was bounced at: Tue, 30 May 2017 11:44:05 UTC
Error code: 6.6.6 for email: test6@ah.com was bounced at: Tue, 30 May 2017 11:44:28 UTC
Error code: 5.5.5 for email: test5@ah.com was bounced at: Tue, 30 May 2017 11:44:21 UTC
Error code: 4.4.4 for email: test4@ah.com was bounced at: Tue, 30 May 2017 11:44:13 UTC
Error code: undefined for email: test7@ah.com was bounced at: undefined
Error code: 9.9.9 for email: test9@ah.com was bounced at: Tue, 30 May 2017 11:44:55 UTC`

It seems as though in some cases, my `request.get()` was performed after the `request.del()` -> this leads to the output log having `Undefined` in some places. How can I ensure the `request.get()` is always executed first?

Comment: Get rid of the callbacks, use promises.

Comment: @loan could you demonstrate this and i will be happy to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using callbacks, you can specify the order by invocking the second async function inside the callback of the first, where first and second is the order with which you want them to execude.

```
first("foo", function() {
  // inside callback of first function
  second("bar", function() {
    // second callback. 
    // At this point both functions have terminated in order
...
```

While this is OK for 2 or 3 nested callbacks, you can easily lose yourself in *callback hell*.

Another way to deal with async functions is to use *Promises*.

When a function returns a Promise you have access to a `.then()` method which takes as an argument the function you want to invoke when the Promise is resolved (the first async functions finishes the async operation)

It will look something like this:

```
something_async_way("foo", "bla").then(function() { // do something });
```

More info on Promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Will try implement using promises before accepting answer

Comment: Ok. I assume you're using `request` module in your node.js file. In that case, since it doesn't support Promises out of the box you'll need to use [this](https://github.com/request/request-promise).

Comment: yeah, i am using the `request` module for hitting the api. I'll look into `request-promise`, thanks.